# Неправильное умножение дробей в PHP

Tags: php

У нас есть две страницы: страница с курсом(0.8) и с количеством валюты "U"(скажем, 1), и страница с обработкой: там количество валюты "U"(1) умножается на курс(а он всё так же 0.8), потом со счёта, на котором хранится валюта "U" снимается количество, указанное на первой странице(1), а на счёт "E" добавляется произведение количества валюты "U"(1) и курса(0.8). Вроде на счёт, где хранится валюта "E" должно начислиться полученное нами произведение (1*0.8), т.е. 0.8, но PHP зачисляет 76491.2 единиц валюты "Е" при том, что снимается только 1 единица валюты "U". Прилагаю выдержки из кода: Страница 1:

```
<input type="text" name="u" placeholder="Кол-во U"> <input type="hidden" name="rate" value="0.8">
```

PHP-коды на второй странице:

```
$utoe = $_POST['u'];
$rate = $_POST['rate'];
//здесь идёт обращение к БД с запросом количества ед. валюты U, где результат мы задаём переменной $u;
$uafter = $u - $utoe; //здесь идёт обращение к БД, где у пользователя становится $uafter ед.валюты "U";
$eto = $u * $rate;
//здесь идёт обращение к БД с запросом количества ед. валюты E, где результат мы задаём переменной $ehave;
$eafter = $ehave + $eto;
//здесь идёт обращение к БД, где у пользователя становится $eafter ед.валюты "U";
```

Примечание: в настоящем коде все обращения к БД построены правильно.
Логи:
[image: U=фунты, E=евро]

Comment: Зачем нам (и вам) весь этот текст, информация про обращения в БД, что на какой странице и тд? Приведите голую выжимку: значения переменных, вычисления, ожидаемый и реальный результаты.

Comment: Короче: PHP каким-то неведомым образом получает 76491.2 как результат выражения, где я просто умножаю 1 на 0.8. Такие свойства проявляет только когда эти значения (1 и 0.8) берутся из текстовых полей на предыдущей странице. Если просто ввести 1*0.8, получаем ожидаемый 0.8.

Comment: Ну так воспользуйтесь отладкой, распечатывайте в процессе все промежуточные значения на всех этапах, ведите подробный лог-файл и т.д. Здесь телепатов нет, а точную информацию вы сообщать не хотите...

Comment: Добавил для желающих логи. Какие-то странные.

Comment: Это по-вашему отладочные логи? Вы вообще понимаете о чём я говорил?

Comment: Ну... Это конечно не очень-то и логи, но возможности сделать лучше на данный момент нет.

Answer (score 1):

Так как не могу комментировать, пишу тут.

Как сказал @klopp, выводите каждое значение (`$u, $rate, $utoe, ...`) отдельно перед вчислениями.

В качестве теста, я умножил `'1'*0.8`, `'1'*'0.8'`, `1*'0.8'`, `1*0.8` и во всех случаях выводилось 0.8. Проверьте, что вы получаете через `POST`, возможно ошибка кроется там. Как дополнительные меры, можно использовать [floatval()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.floatval.php), [intval()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.intval.php).

Answer (score 0):

Дело покрыто мраком, информации недостаточно, просто подскажу два нюанса с вещественными числами:

- числа с плавающей запятой это неточные значения. они не то, чем кажутся. например попробуйте сделать  `var_dump( (0.1 + 0.7) == 0.8 );`
- у вас в текстовом представлении десятичная точка или десятичная запятая? в русской локали вещественные числа *выводятся* с запятой, но обратное неверно! `floatval('0,8')` в любом раскладе равен `0`.

Comment: вот я тоже думаю на хитрую локаль

Comment: А еще веселее, когда такое "вещественное в виде строки" значение с запятой записывается в базу. Если экранирование или плейсхолдеры работают - получим просто число без дробной части. А если экранирования нет, то вознкнет бага, т.к. `0,8` это два числа, а не одно :)